# IICS data preview issue with SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, informatica, iics

New to IICS, when build mapping to populate data by EXEC stored procedure from source, I can preview data from query editor. But when I tried to run preview from source and I got nothing return. Any idea?

[Preview Data from Query Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlLnx.png)

[I can preview data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWg9F.png)

[Not able to preview data when run preview from Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tttbf.png)

I also tried to write data to file, the file generated but only field names without data return.

Comment: Aside... be careful with things like datetime literals which are subject to language/region settings, such as the `SET DATEFORMAT` setting of the server and/or current session. Instead of `01/25/2023 11:00:00` you might wish to use the unambiguous format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`, i.e.: `2023-01-25T11:00:00`.

Comment: This seems to be `run preview`, a preview of data when you run or may be debug the flow. It can be different than a source data preview. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried the date format you suggested. I am still having same issue. Thanks

Comment: @KoushikRoy I tried to populate my source data by EXEC Stored Procedure.  I can preview data from query editor that make me thinking my source is working. But the data  not flow to the downstream expression

Comment: Seems a bug to me...